# jQuery Lightbox kills other JQ scripts

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I wanted to use jQuery Lightbox on my responsive layout and its working. But other JQ scripts: Tynenav and slider doesn;t work after adding jQuery Lightbox. I know about chack for JQ conflicts:"Just needed to add $.noConflict(). to jQuery library" after line with JQ. But i register JQ in my fuctions.php this way

```
if (!is_admin())
{ 
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery'("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"), false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Where should i put $.noConflict() and what extra action i should make to avoid conflict in JQ scripts.
Any help will be greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement that new version of jQuery breaks other jQuery plugins infers that jQuery already exists in page.

If it was added without using `wp_enqueue_script` ie hard coded into a template, it won't deregister. Adding a new version of jQuery over writes the jQuery objectand will wipe out any previously loaded plugins registered to the intial jQuery object.

In the past, many wordpress theme developers put a `noConflict()` call right in the jQuery.js file at the very end.

For starters look in a browser console or in  source view of browser to check inventory and order of scripts. Also in browser console list any errors thrown.

jQUery must load before any dependent plugins or code that uses jQuery.